# Render BitmapFont with size < 1 in Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

My ingame camera has units that 25 times less than screen units so when I render BitmapFont generated for camera which used in non-game screens (settings, level choose etc.) it's even doesn't fit in camera.

I came up with some solutions:

1. Generate font with right size, but `No cap character found in font` exception caught.
2. Scale font with `font.getData().setScale(float scaleXY)` but got this:[image]
3. Increase camera units but I'll need to rewrite a lot of code depending on camera combined matrix.

Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a second 'overlay' camera that is sized differently than the main camera and draw text using that camera.

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(sceneCamera.combined);
batch.begin();
drawSceneThings(batch);
batch.end();

batch.setProjectionMatrix(uiCamera.combined);
batch.begin();
drawUIThings(batch);
batch.end();
```

Otherwise, using [distance field fonts](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts) might give you better results than bitmap fonts since they scale much better, although this will require some work to get the shaders set up and rendering properly.